# How to add money to CoinPayments?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I need to make a transaction of 0.00744000 BTC using the site CoinPayments.net. However, when I click on "Add new deposit address" in my wallet, I can see a 34-character long code. 
Next to it, there is a button "Deposit with Bitcoin client", but when I click on it, an empty tab opens in Chrome. In Chrome's address bar, I can see the 34-character long code and the prefix `bitcoin:`.

However, I don't understand how am I supposed to make the transfer then? I need to convert $50 from my bank account to BTC.

Comment: I don't understand why people vote this as "customer support with a company". OP seems just confused about where to get BTC to deposit.

Answer (score 1):

"Deposit with Bitcoin client" does the opposite of what you need to do.

(Though I'd [read this](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/coinpayments.net?languages=en&stars=1) before making any transactions on that website.)

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the first sentence?

Thanks for the link.

Comment: You need "deposit from bank account".

Comment: Unfortunately that is not offered, so then I would need to have another Bitcoin client for this?

Comment: Yes. (In fact this is a valid reason alone to be suspicious. Because bank transactions are more traceable than Bitcoin payments, so they'd rather commit fraud with bitcoins)